# Automated Kubernetes rolling update when the same tag is pushed to a container registry

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, acr

I frequently update a Docker image using the same tag on Azure Container Registry. I would like to automatically run a rolling update when a new tag is pushed to my ACR, so pods are automatically updated with the latest version of the image.

ACR provides a Webhook feature to automatically call a webhook when a new tag is pushed.

My first approach would be to create webhook in Kubernetes exposed through an ingress and callable from the ACR. The webhook would perfom the rolling update, but it requires to access the Kubernetes API.

Is it possible? Am I in the right direction, or is there a more convenient way to answer my requirement?

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. If ACR can call a webhook whenever a new image is pushed (even with the same tag), you can call a webhook service in your cluster. The service can then, for example, update an annotation in the [PodTemplateSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#podtemplatespec-v1-core) of your Deployment, which triggers a rolling update of your Pods.

However, it requires that the [imagePullPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images) of the containers is set to Always, as the tag of the image remains unchanged. Otherwise, Kubernetes would think that it's still the same image and would use the one that it has previously pulled.

For access to the Kubernetes API, you can do this with a [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) to which you assign the necessary Kubernetes API permissions with [Roles and RoleBindings](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/). Finally, you assign this ServiceAccount to your Pods through the [`serviceAccountName`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#podspec-v1-core) field in the PodSpec.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to run a rolling update (like we can do with kubectl rollout apply) with the kubernetes API without adding a new annotation?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can execute `kubectl rollout restart` with `-v 8` to see what API calls kubectl makes behind the scenes, and you see that it does a PATCH on an annotation named `kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt` in the PodTemplateSpec of the Deployment. So, even `kubectl rollout` is implemented by just updating an annotation in the PodTemplateSpec. You don't need to add a new annotation, you can just patch an existing one, see [PATCH Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#patch-deployment-v1-apps) in the API reference.